# Lebesgue Integral of the indicator (characteristic) function.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, self-learning

For $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$, $x \in X$ and $A \in \mathcal A$, is the following accurate? $$\int_X 1_A(x) \mu(dx) = \int_A \mu(dx) = \mu(A)$$

I'm not sure if my instincts are correct here. Thanks for any clarity.

Comment: it is a **definition**, that is, the RHS is defined to represent the LHS, and yes, its "accurate"

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks. I missed that particular representation of it in the text I'm studying from. Just saw it (it's not really centrally presented). :)

Comment: (note to self: check Wikipedia before posting questions) :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Definition (Lebesgue Integral).** Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space
> and let $E \in \mathcal A$ be a measurable set. Let $s : X \to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable step function of the form
> $$s=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i},$$
> where $α_i ∈ [0,∞)$ and $A_i ∈ \mathcal A$ for $i = 1, \dots , n$. The (Lebesgue) integral of $s$ over $E$ is the number $\int_E
> s\,\mathrm d\mu ∈ [0,∞]$ defined by
> $$\int_E s\,\mathrm d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\mu(E\cap A_i).$$

Define $A_1=A$ for the sake of noation. Let $A\subseteq E$. The indicator function $\mathbf 1_A$ is simple. We may write it as
$$s= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i},$$
where $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_i=0$ for $i>1$. Our integral is therefore equal to
$$\int_E \mathbf 1_A\,\mathrm d\mu=\mu(E\cap A).$$
Since $A\subseteq E$, we have $\mu(A)$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you. Although, did you mean $A \subseteq E$ the first time around?

Comment: @OldDogNewTrick Ah yes, sorry for the typo. Now corrected.